# Using AllArgsConstructor with Spring annotation argument

Tags: java, spring, maven, lombok

I have this class...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("message")
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class MessageController {
...
}
```

I have the following dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The class has two variables that I'm trying to inject via the constructor, and I'm getting this error on the `@AllArgsConstructor` line.

```
"__ cannot be resolved to a type"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's assume you're using Eclipse... 
As described in lombok documentation, you must install lombok as java agent in your Eclipse:

> Eclipse and variants
>   Run lombok.jar as a java app (i.e. doubleclick
>   it, usually) to install. Also add lombok.jar to your project.
>   Supported variants: Springsource Tool Suite, JBoss Developer Studio

If not, take a look at [lombok documentation page](https://projectlombok.org/download.html) for instructions for another IDEs .

Hope it helps.